# How V8 access property when inline cache misses?

Tags: javascript, v8

As referred in [Fast Property Access](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements), we can cache `hidden class address` and `property offset` to access property. 
But how to get a new `property offset` if cache misses(when `hidden class` changes)?

Does `hidden class` include a key-value structure to store `property` and `offset`? If not, then how V8 implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `hidden class` contains a description of where each property is stored. When an inline cache misses, this information is used to compute new access information, and the inline cache is updated with this information.